# Removing vowels from a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm suppose remove all the vowels from the any string that would be entered. I'm trying to make the code as simple as possible.

Thank you for the help.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for i in text:
       i.strip(['i','o','a','u','e'])
       return i
```

Comment: [Relevant question from code review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151716/remove-all-vowels-from-a-string-except-an-initial-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `strip` is the wrong method; it only removes from the beginning and end of a string. Use `.replace(something, '')`.
2. Strings are immutable; a method cannot *modify* a string. `strip` *returns* the modified string.

Comment: Very true, although #1 isn't relevant here, since the OP's code is calling  `.strip` on  single chars.

Comment: @STNDR Just FYI, you can only accept a single answer... when you accept one and then accept another, the first is automatically unmarked :-)

Comment: Lol, I was surprised that mine was accepted over cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's. You should probably consider accepting that one again.

Answer (score 8):

So you call strip on each character.... and then what? You don't update the string, because strings are immutable and `i.strip` is not an inplace operation.

A naive improvement over your solution would filtering characters out inside a list comprehension and then doing a `join` on the result:

```
vowels = {'i','o','a','u','e'}
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join([c for c in text if c not in vowels])
```

A small note: if your string contains mixed case, you may want to either

1. Lowercase `text`, or
2. Augment `vowels` to contain uppercase vowels: `vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')`, or
3. Use `str.casefold` (as per @Adam Smith's comment)—augmenting `vowels` is no longer needed in that case:

   ```
   return ''.join([c for c in text if c.casefold() not in vowels])
   ```

---

You can get *even* better with `str.translate` (this works on python-3.x):

```
mapping = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(vowels, '')) # create a global mapping once
def anti_vowel(text):
    return text.translate(mapping))
```

Comment: Don't need the `[]` in the join.

Comment: @StephenRauch But it's faster _with_ it... let me find you the link. EDIT: here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4909087

Comment: for mixed case -- `...if c.casefold() not in vowels])` is probably best, rather than `[c for c in text.casefold() ...` since then you don't lose the original case

Comment: I'd probably create the translation table as a global, rather than rebuilding it in each `anti_vowel` call.

Comment: @AdamSmith Very nice, thank you. I put that in there.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, thank you, another great improvement there.

Comment: @StephenRauch Here's what core dev Raymond Hettinger has to say about `.join` on a gen exp vs list comp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4014959

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks that is the link coldspeed had above.  If you are paying attention, and hanging out in the right places, you can learn something new everyday...

Comment: @StephenRauch Ah, right, I missed his edit. :) FWIW, if `.join` didn't do two passes it would be less efficient, since it would have to do concatenation in a loop, [which is bad](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Answer (score 0):

This code worked too! The dude who wrote the anwser deleted their post. Shame it worked really well.

```
liz = ("Totally not going to hitting the big bong at the event")
import re

def anti_vowel(text):
    print re.sub('[aeiou]', '', text)

anti_vowel(liz)

output: 
Ttlly nt gng t httng th bg bng t th vnt
```

Comment: The deleted answer contains some incorrect information. But yes, they could've just edited that out. That regex code works, but I suspect that using the built-in `str.translate` is faster.

Comment: Feel free to do a timeit test, but I can guarantee this regex replacement is the slowest, followed by your loopy replace. The fastest and second fastest by far is translate and the list comp.

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip` is not an in-place operation and takes a string as an argument. Therefore, your code will not work as desired.

You can use [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) to efficiently remove certain characters from your string. You may see an order of magnitude better performance for larger strings.

Character removal can be performed with `bytearray.translate` directly, without the need to use `str.maketrans`.

```
def anti_vowel_bytes(s):
    b = bytearray()
    b.extend(s.encode())
    b = b.translate(None, b'aeiou')
    return b.decode('utf-8') 

def anti_vowel_str(s, mapping):
    return s.translate(mapping)

vowels = set('aeiou')
mapping = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(vowels, ''))

test = 'alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta'*100000
res1 = anti_vowel_bytes(test)
res2 = anti_vowel_str(test, mapping)

assert res1 == res2

%timeit anti_vowel_bytes(test)            # 20 ms
%timeit anti_vowel_str(test, mapping)     # 398 ms
```

Comment: Slightly unfair as of now, because both vowel and mapping's definitions can be moved outside, otherwise they're timed as part of the timeit at each iteration. Otherwise this is a nice find.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Fair point; updated the benchmarking. Yep, it's amazing the new things you can learn from the official docs.